# Can I install Ubuntu on dell inspiron 3521 with windows 7

Tags: dell, format

Specification: Ram2B ,BIOS A06

Comment: Yes, you can ))

Comment: You can. I had an old Dell studio(2009) and i upgraded the BIOS ver to A11 before the install(just FYI).

Comment: Also see http://askubuntu.com/questions/206407/how-do-i-find-out-which-version-and-derivative-of-ubuntu-is-right-for-my-hardware

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, but if you want a better experience with that amount of RAM and in that specific hardware I would recommend using a light flavour of Ubuntu instead (Xubuntu or Ubuntu Mate).

http://xubuntu.org/

https://ubuntu-mate.org/